# How Do I Get Firebase IssuerSigningKey In Asp net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on mobile app that uses Firebase for authentication but I am unable to verify a Jwt from Firebase on asp net core 2 app, the problem  I have is getting the IssuerSigningKey,  here is  a sample of my code in asp net core start up class. From Firebase Documentation, they say I should obtain the certificate from https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com. I cannot proceed from there

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddJwtBearer(options =>
   {
       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {
           ValidateIssuer = true,
           ValidateAudience = true,
           ValidateLifetime = true,
           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
           ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
           ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:aud"],
           IssuerSigningKey = 

       };
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found an answer from this site https://blog.markvincze.com/secure-an-asp-net-core-api-with-firebase/ all I needed to add was options.Authority = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"]; and removing the issuer signing key

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
     options.Authority = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
   {
       ValidateIssuer = true,
       ValidateAudience = true,
       ValidateLifetime = true,
       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
       ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
       ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:aud"],

   };
});
```

Comment: Isn't it important to validate the IssuerSigningKey?